# Draw colored wuline with C

Tags: algorithm, antialiasing

I'm trying to draw colored line(RGB332) with [Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm)  , but the example is about grayscale and the width seems to be not modifiable .

I only got a poor MCU to drive the RGB332 LCD .The colored version seems much differ from the grayscale algorithm,and it shows everything but the correct AA-line on my LCD.

Is there a colored version of Xiaolin Wu's line or other antialiasing  line algorithm available for C code ?

Comment: This algorithm tackles brightness, so you just have to use an HSB model for your color and choose an appropriate Hue value for your color.

Comment: I know little about the HSB model ,does it mean the Weighting of edge is just like  the greyscale one , but it should be done by R \G \B path each with different factor?

Comment: I mean choose some Hue and Saturation, and use the algorithm to get the Brightness, and then convert (HSB) to (RGB) if needed.

Comment: Seems the RGB332 color is not just add same weighting (like +1 )  to each color channel, the color turn out to be strange. Is there any RGB to HSB sample?